# enable offline files for all users home drives via Group policy or other

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, offline-files

I am trying to get all users of particular notebooks to make the user's H: drive offline. I know you can do it manually but is there a way to set this value somewhere so that users don't have to do it themselves?

I am running 2008R2 domain controllers and Windows 7 clients. I have folder redirection enabled but I want to make the users H: drive available to them when they are offline.

I know the group policies are located in the computer configuration>Policies>administrative templates>Network> but there doesn't seem to be any place to select which folders/drives will be offline files without a user's input.

Is there another method, without using Group Policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the section of GPO you mentioned, I see a policy named:

> Administratively assigned offline files

This sounds exactly like what you're trying to achieve unless I'm missing something.